# Invalid memory access when using binary research tree

Tags: c++

Here is my codes.

```
#include<iostream>

template<class Elem>
class BinNode
{
public:
    virtual Elem& getVal() = 0;
    virtual void setVal(const Elem&) = 0;
    virtual BinNode* left() = 0;
    virtual BinNode* right() = 0;
    virtual void setLeft(BinNode*) = 0;
    virtual void setRight(BinNode*) = 0;
    virtual bool isLeaf() = 0;
};//abstract class

template<class Elem>
class BinNodePtr:public BinNode<Elem>
{
public:
    Elem val;
    BinNodePtr* lc;
    BinNodePtr* rc;
    BinNodePtr()
    {
        lc = rc = NULL;
    }
    ~BinNodePtr()
    {
        delete lc;
        delete rc;
    }
    void setVal(const Elem& e)
    {
        val = e;
    }
    Elem& getVal()
    {
        return this->val;
    }
    void setLeft(BinNode<Elem>* e)
    {
            lc = (BinNodePtr<Elem>*)e;
    }
    void setRight(BinNode<Elem>* e)
    {
        rc = (BinNodePtr<Elem>*)e;
    }
    bool isLeaf()
    {
        if(this->lc == NULL && this->rc == NULL)
        return true;
        return false;
    }
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* left()
    {
        return lc;
    }
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* right()
    {
        return rc;
    }
};

template<class Elem>
class BST
{
public:
    BinNodePtr<Elem> *root;
    int nodenum;
    void deleteElem(BinNodePtr<Elem>* start);
    void midorder(BinNodePtr<Elem>* start);
public:
    BST()
    {
        root = NULL;
        nodenum = 0;
    }
    ~BST()
    {
        deleteElem(root);
    }
    bool insert(BinNodePtr<Elem>* ptr,const Elem &e);
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* getRoot(){return root;}
};
template<class Elem>
void BST<Elem>::deleteElem(BinNodePtr<Elem>* start)
{
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* temp =(BinNodePtr<Elem>*) start;
    if(temp == NULL) return;
    deleteElem((BinNodePtr<Elem>*)temp->left());
    deleteElem((BinNodePtr<Elem>*)temp->right());
    delete temp;
}

template<class Elem>
void BST<Elem>::midorder(BinNodePtr<Elem> *start)
{
    if(start == NULL) return;
    midorder(start->lc);
    printf("%d ",start->getVal());
    midorder(start->rc);
}

template<class Elem>
bool BST<Elem>::insert(BinNodePtr<Elem>*ptr,const Elem &e)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        ptr = new BinNodePtr<Elem>;
        ptr->lc = NULL;
        ptr->rc = NULL;
        ptr->val = e;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(ptr->val < e || ptr->val == e)
            {
        ptr = ptr->right();
        insert(ptr->rc,e);
        }
        else
            {
        ptr = ptr->left();
        insert(ptr->lc,e);
            }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    BST<int> myBST;
    myBST.insert(myBST.root,10);
    myBST.insert(myBST.root,20);
    myBST.insert(myBST.root,5);
    myBST.insert(myBST.root,30);
    printf("%d",myBST.getRoot()->getVal());

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

There are some functions which are not used in my program.I focus on the "insert" function.When I debug this ,the program breaks down at `printf("%d",myBST.getRoot()->getVal());`saying "invalid memory access",Why and how to solve it?

Comment: and I think there are also some mistakes in my function"insert".I think not even a number was inserted , but I don't know how to fix it.:(

Comment: Yould you be so kind to reduce the code as far as possible, preserving the problem at hand? People are unlikely to read through all of it, especially if you say yourself that there are unused functions in it. iow, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If you don't have the privileges to edit your question, feel free to create a new one and delete this one.

Comment: What is a binary _research_ tree? Do you mean search?

Comment: Yes,I will reduce my code ,sorry.

Comment: I don't have the privilege to edit my question , but I will obey the SSCCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that in C++ arguments are by default passed by value, that means their value is *copied* to the argument in the called function. When you change an argument in the function, you only change its local copy, no changes to the copy will be propagated to the caller.

To change an argument in the caller, you have to pass it by reference, like

```
bool insert(BinNodePtr<Elem>*& ptr,const Elem& e);
```

This will make the `ptr` argument a reference to the pointer, so changes to it will propagate to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the ptr argument in the insert function, you should pass the address of it, like so:

```
template<class Elem>
bool BST<Elem>::insert(BinNodePtr<Elem>**ptr,const Elem &e)
```

or pass a reference to it.

Comment: No no no, that's the old C way, in C++ we have references.